# How can I get the "id" of the current visible div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried

```
var currentVis = $("div:visible");
alert(currentVis);
```

If the div in question is like: `<div id="DIVONE">` I want `var currentVis` to alert `DIVONE`. All I get is `object object`.

Comment: with this I got UNDEFINED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var currentVis = $("div:visible");
alert(currentVis[0].id);

 -or-

alert(currentVis.attr("id"));
```

Comment: It works if fiddle but not on my page I'll have to work on it

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentVis = $("div:visible");
var id = currentVis.attr('id');
```

Comment: with this I got a blank alert

Answer (score 1):

If your selector finds a div, just refer to its id via:

```
currentVis[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div:visible").each(function(){
if($(this).attr("id")=="DIVONE"){
    //do somethings
}});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood or I did not explain . I have a click function to go back in a form. I want a statement this will tell me the ID of the current visible div